# MvcPaging using Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, paging

I want to use MvcPaging in a PartialView. I have a search page and I need to paginate the results. So far, only the first page from the results appears - when I am trying to go to page 2 I get in the console a 500 error and nothing happens.

Here are the two actions from controller:

```
public PartialViewResult SearchResults(string lat, string lng, double? dist)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            string address = Request["address"];
            string latitude = lat;
            string longitude = lng;

            GeoCoordinate coord = new GeoCoordinate(Double.Parse(latitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Double.Parse(longitude, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            IQueryable<Restaurants> near = (from r in _db.Restaurants select r);
            results = new List<Restaurants>();
            foreach (Restaurants restaurant in near)
            {
                double latBD = (double)restaurant.Latitude;
                double lngDB = (double)restaurant.Longitude;
                if (new GeoCoordinate(latBD, lngDB).GetDistanceTo(coord) <= dist * 1000)
                {
                    results.Add(restaurant);
                }
            }
            return PartialView("_SearchResult", results.ToPagedList(0, 2));
        }
        return PartialView("Search");
    }

    public ActionResult PaginationAjax(int? page)
    {
        int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;
        return PartialView("_SearchResult", results.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, 2));
    }
```

And the partial view:

```
@model IPagedList<Restaurants>
@using MvcPaging
foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <blockquote>
            <h3><a href="Details?Id=@item.Id" target="_blank">@item.Name</a></h3>
        </blockquote>
    }
    <div class="pager">
        @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "searchResults" }).Options(o => o.Action("PaginationAjax"))
    </div>
```

Does anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:
Error

```
GET http://localhost/TakeASeat/Restaurants/PaginationAjax?page=2&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1431698681795 500 (Internal Server Error)
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-2.1.3.js:8625
jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.3.js:8161
asyncRequest @ jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:128
(anonymous function) @ jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js:138
jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.3.js:4430
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery-2.1.3.js:4116
```

Comment: can you please add the contents of the 500 error that you're receiving?

Comment: @AnthonyShaw take a look now

Comment: can you show the actual 500 error, this is the console output indicating there is a 500 error. if you open that url (http://localhost/TakeASeat/Restaurants/PaginationAjax?page=2&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest&_=1431698681795) directly, what error are you seeing?

Comment: @AnthonyShaw Ok, I see the problem now. It seems like "results" is null in the "PaginationAjax" action. Any thought on how to solve this without querying the db twice?